# A Tower problem. Am I on the right way?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Lucy likes building towers and hence he built $n$ towers out of identical pieces on a sequence of n squares. 
Once he finished his construction and his towers have heights $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ respectively, Pete came and decided to play a game with him.

a) In each round, Pete chooses a positive integer $k$ and picks two neighbouring towers ($k$ cannot exceed 
the height of any of the two chosen towers). Lucy then chooses one of these towers and moves $k$ pieces 
from it to the other tower. Whenever a tower is of height $0$ the square on which it is placed disappears 
and (unless it is first or last one) its two neighbouring squares get connected. What is the necessary and sufficient condition on the sum of the towers’ heights $N$ so that:

• for every initial setup $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ with $a_1 + a_2 + \dotsm + a_n = N$ Pete can force Lucy to put all the pieces into one single tower of height $N$?

• Pete can force Lucy to empty at least one square?

b) Fix a positive integer $k$. In each round, Pete picks a positive integer $\ell$ and chooses $\ell$ neighbouring towers. Then Lucy either increases by $1$ or decreases by $1$ heights of all chosen towers at once (towers may have negative heights and they no longer disappear). Find the maximal number m so that Petecan always force Lucy in a finite number of rounds to have at least m towers with heights divisible by k.

I rearranged $2$ dice from the second tower, i.e. $k=2$ and so on $4$ to the tower with an height of $3$, and arithmetic peogression with difference of $4$: $a_1=3 , a_2=7, \ldots$.
In B  I rearranged from $7$ dice $11$, from $19$ to $23$ and I think $k=3$. 
Am I on the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I only have an answer to the first question, and only in the case $n=2$. In that case, the quick answer is "usually no". If $N$ is odd and $n=2$: Pete can never force Lucy to empty a square. The two towers always have different heights, so Lucy can always move blocks from the taller tower to the shorter one without emptying it.

If $N$ is even and $n=2$, Pete can still only empty a square if the two towers have equal heights. The turn before this, Pete can only force the two towers to have the same height if $a_1=3a_2$ (or the other way around). Then Pete can say $a_1$, and Lucy has to make the two towers have the same height, or else empty tower 1. That state is only possible if $N$ is a multiple of 4. Two turns before this, Pete has to be able to force Lucy into any of the three losing states: $a_2=0$, $a_1=3a_2$ or $a_1=a_2$. This is only possible if $N$ is a multiple of 8 and the towers start in one of the proportions $a_1=a_2$ or $3a_1=5a_2$. In general, we need a relation $ca_1=da_2$, where $c$ and $d$ are integers adding up to a power of 2. You could prove this by induction on the number of steps in which Pete can force a win.